# Win10: Can install an unsigned driver, but it disables it after reboot?

Tags: drivers

I can install an unsigned driver (by following pretty much any one of the zillion guides on google), and the driver works. However as soon as I reboot windows 10, it disables the driver that was installed.

And just to be sure, after rebooting and seeing that the driver was disabled, I then rebooted again into the "allow unsigned drivers" mode, and bingo, my driver was enabled and working again.

So the first question is, why on earth does the option even exist to install the unsigned driver by rebooting into that special mode, if it's still going to disable the driver as soon as you boot into normal mode? And why don't any of those websites warn you that'll happen?

And the second question is, can I make it permanently accept the driver? It's a driver that I hacked (to improve) for my own personal computer, so the security certificate is of course no longer valid. And no I'm not distributing it to anyone except myself, so I only need it to work on my one computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can globally allow unsigned drivers permanently by editing a local group policy value.

1. Right click Start button > Run > gpedit.msc
2. Find the following hive: `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Driver Installation\Code Signing for Device Drivers`
3. Select `Enabled` and then on the dropdown, choose the `Ignore` setting.
4. Restart machine.

To answer your other questions: The option to boot into that mode allows that for unsigned drivers is solely for testing. In fact, it is called windows testing mode. All drivers should be signed for security purposes and regular joes should not be able to easily, permanently run unsigned drivers.

Answer (score 0):

if you look carefully at the description of the Code signing option shown above it says it only works for Windows Server 2008 and XP machines, so it will not work for Windows 10 or 11.    Thus it is no good for latest machines.
Only option I know is to disable "Secure boot" but that can open up hackers getting into your machine on Boot.      Be aware.